# Add SwiftUI ListView which allows both Pull to Refresh feature and Pagination

Tags: ios, firebase, listview, swiftui

I'm currently trying, to implement a SwiftUI ListView, where the contents of the list should be able to be refreshed if the user pulls down on the list to refresh the contents; and equally importantly, that the list should be able to paginate as I do not want to load the entire contents of the elements of the list on the load of the view. The data is retrieved from within a Firebase Realtime database.

The code for this is pretty straight forward:

```
List(postStore.posts) { post in

    NavigationLink(destination: PostDetails(post: post)) {

        PostView(post: post)

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Posts", displayMode: .inline)
    .onAppear(perform: fetchPosts)

}
```

The postStore is just the ref to the DataStore to Firebase and the fetchPost function is just the call to the datastore to fetch the posts.

I am unsure how to implement the two main features, which is the pull to refresh and/or pagination for the ListView!?

Does anyone have suggestions and/or has been able to successfully implement the two features using SwiftUI?

Comment: For Pull to refresh you probably need a UIViewRepresentable

Comment: @davidev for a UIScrollView or UITable!? And if possible can you elaborate on how I could implement?